# What defines the PHP error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have been wondering on this question for a while.  I have two PHP programs that are almost exactly identical except for the fact that on of them is a function and the other isn't.  Furthermore one works and the other send back the error:

```
Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object
```

I fixed the one that wasn't working by omitting the variables and inserting definitive strings and adding `$con->errno` instead of `mysqli_errno`.  However, when I replaced the strings with the variables again the problem returned.

So, my question is: what causes this error and how would I fix it.  Also, why is the error coming up in the second code and not the first?

**The First Code (works)**

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("database info");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $stmt = $con->query("SELECT coordinator, announcements, description, comments, picture FROM Class_data WHERE class_year = '" .$class. "';");

    $result_row = $stmt->fetch_object();

    $coordinator = $result_row->coordinator;
    $announcement = $result_row->announcements;
    $description = $result_row->description;
    $comments = $result_row->comments;
    $picturepath = $result_row->picture;

    mysqli_error($con);

    mysqli_close($con);

    if ($picturepath == "")
    {
        $picturepath = "../images/AlumnLogo.png";
    }
?>
```

**Second Code (doesn't work)**

```
<?php

function fetch($page, $content1, $content2, $content3)
{
    $con = new mysqli("database info");
    if ($con->errno)
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     $stmt = $con->query("SELECT '" .$content1. "' , '" .$content2. "' , '" .$content3. "' FROM '" .$page. "';");

    $result_row = $stmt->fetch_object();

    $content = array();
    $content[0] = $result_row->body;
    $content[1] = $result_row->calendar;
    $content[2] = $result_row->announcements;
    $output = implode("--",$content);

    mysqli_error($con);

    mysqli_close($con);

    return $output;
}

?>
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using as the method of checking for a mysqli connection error was broken and you had to do it specific ways in different versions http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quoting your column names using single quotes. You cannot do that, you need to quote table- and column names using backticks (in case of reserved words, spaces, etc.) and only (non-integer...) values need to be quoted using single or double quotes.

Change your code to:

```
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT `" .$content1. "` , `" .$content2. "` , `" .$content3. "` FROM `" .$page. "`;");
                            ^ All these
```

By the way, I assume you are using a white-list for your table- and column names. If not, you should to avoid sql injection.

It is also a good idea to add error handling to your database calls. An easy way using mysqli, is to put `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` at the start of your script. This will cause mysqli to throw exceptions so that you do not have to check for individual errors on each database call.

Comment: So, when the query returns false, it spits back that error. Thank you for making that clear

Comment: @Ignatius_Gim I just added some things about error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply means that you try to call a method on something that is not an object. The problem is that `$stmt` is not an object!

This happens because there is an error in your SQL Statemetn. `$con->query()` retuns `false` in such a case. Therefore, what you try to execute is something like `false->fetch_object();`. And `false` isn't an object...

Try to print your generated SQL Statement. It will probabely contain some syntax errors. Fix those, and it will work